# Angular material dialog outside iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, angular-material, dialog, modal-dialog

I'm having a problem displaying an Angular material dialog outside of an iframe.
I have two applications, an application that is used to present other applications through an iframe and another application that is displayed inside the iframe.
The second app (the one that renders inside the iframe) has different dialogs but they are centered inside the iframe, I would like them to be centered relative to the first app.

I hope that with the images you can understand what I am trying to achieve.

Current:
[image: Imagen1]
What I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Imagen2]

In my **first application**, I have a simple iframe where I use a variable to assign the address where the front of the application that I want to display is located.

```
<iframe id="iframe" allowfullscreen [hidden]="condition" scrolling="no" [src]="url | domsecure" title="Navigation"></iframe>
```

In my **second application**, I have called a function to display an Angular material dialog.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { DialogComponent } from '../dialog/dialog.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test',
  templateUrl: './test.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test.component.css']
})
export class TestComponent {

  constructor(private matDialog: MatDialog) { }

  public showDialog(): void {
    this.matDialog.open(DialogComponent);
  }

}
```

I am using Angular 11.0.5
PD: My first post here :3

Comment: You should provide some code samples, also, consider signaling the first application to display the dialog outside the iframe

Comment: This can be solved by using the dialog declared outside the `iframe` from inside the iframe. You can access it by just calling `window.top.window.document.getElementById('your dialog id outside the iframe this code is being used')`. The drawback is that you'll have to make your dialog manipulable via `DOM` so you'll have to declare it as a custom [angular element](https://angular.io/guide/elements) (this approach is actually the solution our team implemented as we had the exact same requirement)

Comment: @luiscla27 Thank you very much. I'm going to try... =)